# Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with my import.sql file on a Spring Boot application but i can not figure out where the error is. I Got the following error on the console:

```
2017-12-28 18:31:24.496[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10866[0;39m [2m--
-[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m 
[36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000388: 
Unsuccessful: insert into convidado (id, nome, quantidade_acompanhantes)
[2m2017-12-28 18:31:24.496[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10866[0;39m [2m--
-[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m 
[36morg.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Syntax 
error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO CONVIDADO (ID, NOME, 
QUANTIDADE_ACOMPANHANTES) [*]"; expected "DIRECT, SORTED, DEFAULT, VALUES, 
SET, (, WITH, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
insert into convidado (id, nome, quantidade_acompanhantes) [42001-196]
```

Comment: Please add your script, we just need the bit that starts insert into convidado (id, nome, quantidade_acompanhantes) and then the next line

Comment: Could you show us your import.sql file ?

Comment: INSERT INTO CONVIDADO (ID, NOME, QUANTIDADE_ACOMPANHANTES) VALUES (1, 'Pedro', 2);
INSERT INTO CONVIDADO (ID, NOME, QUANTIDADE_ACOMPANHANTES) VALUES (2, 'Maria', 3);
INSERT INTO CONVIDADO (ID, NOME, QUANTIDADE_ACOMPANHANTES) VALUES (3, 'Ricardo', 1);

Comment: When you created `CONVIDADO` table, did you specify that `ID` column is `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Comment: Hi Luay Abdulraheem, yes the ID is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @josecarlosSiqueira, I am facing the problem. Could you solve the issue in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT` statement is used to add new rows into database table.

Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Column 1, column 2)
VALUES (value 1, value2)
```

Example of an `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO student (id, name, age)
VALUES (1, 'harry', 22);
```